# versioning microservices developed using Serverless framework

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, microservices, serverless-framework, auto-versioning

Our project structure is:

```
->package.json
->src/services
   -->serviceA/package.json
   -->serviceB/package.json
```

We have the following branches:

Develop, staging, master -> deployed to their respective environments

How should the microservices versioning be handled automatically?

We use CodePipeline/code build for CI/CD with a pipeline per branch strategy. Respective Pipeline is triggered when code is merged from feature branch -> develop or develop -> staging , or staging -> ,master

How can we auto version the microservices?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about how to use Git. In fact, I can't figure out if *any* of these tags are really relevant. You might change the major number of a microservice if you change the services it offers, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing a plugin that updates version on `sls deploy`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-ssm-version-tracker